# extending highcharts with an ajax load event

Tags: javascript, ajax, highcharts

I have a php, jquery, jqueryMobile, highcharts page with several charts on one page.

No i added an ajax call to load event to get live data into the charts. but i have to declare this in every Highcharts object, no matter which way i try it's not working as global function.

Here parts of the code i have and which is working

```
            $(document).ready(function () {

            // define sensorName
            var sensorName = "rflinkstation";

            chart1 = new Highcharts.chart({
                "chart": {
                    "renderTo": sensorName,
                    "events": {
                        "load": function() {
                            var series = this.series[0];
                            setInterval(function() {
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: 'sensorAjaxData.php',
                                    success: function(point) {    
                                        console.log("ajax request for = " + sensorName);                            

                                        // add the point
                                        series.addPoint(point, true, true);
                                    },
                                    cache: false,
                                    data: { "sensorName": sensorName,
                                        "stationID": <?php echo $stationID;?>,
                                    }
                                });
                            }, 60000);
                        }   
                    }
                },          
                "series": [{
```

...

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

            // define sensorName
            var sensorName = "batteryvolt1";

            chart2 = new Highcharts.chart({             
                "chart": {
                    "renderTo": sensorName,
                    "events": {
                        "load": function() {
                            var series = this.series[0];
                            setInterval(function() {
                                $.ajax({
                                    url: 'sensorAjaxData.php',
                                    success: function(point) {    
                                        console.log("ajax request for = " + sensorName);                            

                                        // add the point
                                        series.addPoint(point, true, true);
                                    },
                                    cache: false,
                                    data: { "sensorName": sensorName,
                                        "stationID": <?php echo $stationID;?>,
                                    }
                                });
                            }, 60000);
                        }   
                    }
                },
                "series": [{
```

....

What i try to achieve is to put the "load" function into a function to prevent copy pasting allot of code.

but if i declare something like

```
function getData(sensorName) {
```

and

```
events: { load: setInterval(getData(sensorName),6000) }
```

i loose the object and get this.series is undefined
My programming knoledge comes from pre object orinted programming and i do not fully understand the explanations in how to extend highcharts. Also the Highcharts live data example is written so that chart is a global variable and works only with one chart on a page.

so my question is how can i extend Highcharts with a load event that takes "sensorName" as argument and does an ajax call and insertrs the returned data into the right chart?

And a side question why is something like:

```
var series = this.series[0];
$.ajax({
  ...
  series.addPoint(point)
  ...
```

working, and this not

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  this.series[0].addPoint(point)
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The `this` (Window object) inside of `setInterval()` function is not the same `this` (Chart object) as in `chart.events.load()` function. You can for example set the second parameter in `getData()` function which will indicate chart. Now `getData()` looks like this:

```
function getData(sensorName, chart) {
  var series = chart.series[0];

  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/bTNHrHVJmG?indent=2',
    success: function(point) {
      console.log('AJAX request for = ' + sensorName);

      // add the point
      series.addPoint(point, true, true);
    },
    data: {
      sensorName: sensorName,
      stationID: sensorName + 'ID' //<?php echo $stationID;?>,
    },
    cache: false
  });
};
```

and it call in load event looks like this:

```
load: function() {
  var chart = this;

  setInterval(function() {
    getData(chart.options.chart.renderTo, chart);
  }, 5000);
}
```

Take a look at the example I prepared for you.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/a40qvy47/